# BULK INSERT permission on a single database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I work on a company that has straight IT security manners. I was hired as a Database Analyst in order to optimize some processes in our team. The problem is that I only have read and write permissions and I'm trying to work out in getting advanced permissions on the databases. Currently we have a lot of Databases in a single server and we can only work on a single Database, I was wondering if the `BULK INSERT` permission could be given to a single database or would that be permission to the whole server?

I've searched through the web about this but I got a little confused. This is what I found out. In order to use BULK INSERT I should have `INSERT` permission to the desired table or database and the `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` which is a server wide permission.
If I was given `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` permission on the whole database and the `INSERT` permission on a single database, wouldn't I be able to only `BULK INSERT` in that single database, since I don't have `INSERT` permission on other databases?

Is it possible to restrict the use of `BULK INSERT` to a single database on a server that has multiple databases?

Sorry about the text wall, and thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok folks,

I've asked this on Brazilian msdn forum as well and I got the answer (Forum discussion: [BULK INSERT por DATABASE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/admingeralpt/thread/31af817d-237c-4bd7-855d-8667baf39f6f)). The user [Roberson Ferreira _](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/roberson%20ferreira%20_/?ws=usercard-mini) helped me. I imagine you can't read Portuguese so I will describe the answer here.

**Answer:**
It doesn't matter if the `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` is server-wide, the user won't be able to `BULK INSERT` into a certain database if they don't have the `INSERT` permission as well. The `INSERT` permission is a database/table-level permission.

Additionally, the `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` is not going to grant the user any other permissions over the server or database, all the user will be able to do is `BULK INSERT` in the database where they have `INSERT` permission as well.